# Facebook Graph Python for Event Information Mining

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am currently able to return local Facebook events via Facebook SDK Python like this:

```
    import facebook # pip install facebook-sdk
    import json

    ACCESS_TOKEN = 'CAACEdEose0cBAP0G6qGRqHsalEB9YKEUBNny3r3WQZBizPrrznkYX36kZBo2Oy2mbiMjOkI5FJa27bIcUN4Do16VrOw4eDL99ZBNKRAjVfakvNXUXtT8K9uU29fIwq6JJQ9lsQZConkwvzv1IElMU30EGms0QYxX8sIsjFogrzE00iBmvpOltIbfgFnO7BoO75xKaUbk5NTDNIYAy0tKGZAuwabzmH8oZD'


    def pp(o):
        print json.dumps(o, indent=1)

    # Create a connection to the Graph API with your access token

    g = facebook.GraphAPI(ACCESS_TOKEN)

    print
    print '---------------'
    print 'Events'
    print '---------------'
    pp(g.request("search", {'q' : 'Evansville, IN', 'type' : 'event'}))
```

It returns something like this:

```
{
"id": "565819520206832",
"start_time": "2014-11-07T19:15:00-0600",
"location": "Evansville, IN",
"name": "Evansville Icemen vs. Wheeling Nailers",
"end_time": "2014-11-08T03:15:00-0600"
},
```

I am trying to filter these results to only events that are happening now or in the future.

I tried this with no luck:

```
pp(g.request("search", {'q' : 'Evansville, IN', 'type' : 'event', 'until' : 'today'}))
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be working for me:

```
currentTime = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S")
print
print('---------------')
print('Events')
print('---------------')
t=g.request("search",{ 'q' : 'Evansville', 'type' : 'event', 'limit' : 5, 'since_date'  :   'currentTime'})


pp(t)
```